# MySQL - return unique record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Table: products
-----------------------------------------------------
|  id  |      name                |  other fields...
-----------------------------------------------------
|  20   |      Intel i5 4690K     |   ...
|  21   |      AMD A6-7400K       |   ...
|  23   |      AMD A8-3850        |   ...
|  ...  |      ...                |   ...
```

and table product_details:

```
Table: products_details
-----------------------------------------------
|  id  |  product_id  |  option_id  |  value  |
-----------------------------------------------
|  1   |      20      |     2478    |  55032  |
|  2   |      20      |     2482    |  55051  |
|  3   |      21      |     2478    |  54966  |
|  4   |      21      |     2482    |  55050  |
|  5   |      22      |     2478    |  55032  |
|  5   |      22      |     2482    |  55050  |
-----------------------------------------------

2478 = Number of Cores
2482 = Manufacturer

55032 = 4 cores
55050 = 6 cores
```

I'm trying to get records where products are only 4 cores and from AMD:

```
Select
  product_details.product_id,
  products.name,
  product_details.option_id,
  product_details.value
From
  product_details Inner Join
  products On product_details.product_id = products.id
Where
  product_details.option_id In (2478, 2482) And
  product_details.value In (55032, 55050)
```

SQL above gives me double records

```
product_id  name                 option_id  value   
20          Intel i5 4690K       2478       55032
21          AMD A6-7400K         2482       55050
23          AMD A8-3850K         2478       55032
23          AMD A8-3850K         2482       55050
```

Obviously, it won't work with IN. Any ideas?

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: Is it better by adding `DISTINCT product_details.product_id` at the beginning?

Comment: @dotnetom Expected output are products which are only 4 cores and only from AMD. In this case, only product #23

Comment: @Baruchel Distinct still returns 4 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `AMD` `4 CORES`, This query works fine.

You need to do inner join Twice on `product_details` to get `manufacturer` as well as `no of cores`.

Here is the [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa4ad/1)

```
Select
          product_details.product_id,
          products.name,
          product_details.option_id,
          product_details.value
        From
          product_details 
          Inner Join
          products On product_details.product_id = products.id AND product_details.option_id=2478
          INNER JOIN product_details P2 ON P2.product_id = product_details.product_id AND P2.option_id=2482
        Where
          product_details.value = 55032 And
          P2.value = 55050
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your query as written selects all options and all values for the #cores option. You would do better to break it down into a nested subquery:

1. Find the `product_details` records specifying only the desired value for the desired option. (The inner query.)
2. Find the `products` records whose `id`s match those returned by the previous step. (The outer query.)

Comment: Tried that, but no luck. If you can post example of your solution that would be great.

Comment: I'll have to sleep on it. I just spotted an error in my initial assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

First if you need only AMD manufacture then where is the option of this value ?
you said that:

```
2478 = Number of Cores
2482 = Manufacturer
55032 = 4 cores
55050 = 6 cores
```

Ok, But where were the `value`of the `option_id = 2482` ?
you must know them and include them in your `Where` clause.

Also I prefer to use `Left Join` rather than `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Each option can have multiple values. Each product can have multiple options. Product details table contains all product options and values.

Comment: Right, I only wonder where are the available options for the `2482 option_id` ?
in manufacturer values you must have some records like 'AMD', 'Intel' ... and so on